# How to transform a Sink<T> into a Sink<V>?

Tags: dart

I have a method that can emit its output into a given `Sink<Node>`.

I wanted to pipe that into `stdout` which is a `Sink<List<int>>`.

Supposing I have a function `convert` that converts `Node` to `List<int>`, how can I transform `stdout` into a `Sink<Node>`, so that it will print my Tree to the console?

Comment: Should've mentioned: without creating a simple class to the job :) as that's the trivial answer, but annoying to create a class where a function should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made this example showing how you can do it with a StreamController:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class Message {
  String text;
  Message(this.text);
}

void main() {
  final controller = StreamController<Message>();
  stdout.addStream(controller.stream
      .map((var msg) => msg.text)
      .transform(const Utf8Encoder()));

  var messageSink = controller.sink;
  messageSink.add(Message('Hello World'));
}
```

The StreamController in this example takes `Message` objects and converts them into `List<int>` by first using `map` to convert the `Message` to String object and then use a transformer to convert the String into a List of UTF8 bytes.

Comment: looks like `StreamController` is a sink, so I just passed it as is to my method which takes a `Sink`, it's not necessary to call `controller.sink`.

Comment: Correct but I didn't know how important it was for you that it was only a sink. The sink property is documented as "Returns a view of this object that only exposes the StreamSink interface.".

Answer (score 1):

I've filed: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50607

Here is how I solved this:

```dart
class _MappedSink<From, To> implements Sink<From> {
  final To Function(From) _transform;
  final Sink<To> _sink;
  const _MappedSink(this._sink, this._transform);

  @override
  void add(From data) => _sink.add(_transform(data));
  @override
  void close() => _sink.close();
}

extension SinkMap<To> on Sink<To> {
  Sink<From> map<From>(To Function(From) transform) =>
      _MappedSink(this, transform);
}
```